# Skipping bytes Java NIO SocketChannel

Tags: java, sockets, nio

Let's assume I have SocketChannel is waiting for read.
I don't want to read the first K bytes (as in, I don't want to copy them to a byte buffer, just skip them).

Is there anyway of doing so? there is no skip() method available.

Comment: This question assumes the operating system even exposes an operation to throw away data from a socket.   I've never heard of such a call for TCP, though I believe recv will only return once per datagram, even if the buffer provided is too small to hold the whole thing.  For example lseek errors if passed a socket:  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html

Comment: What you are doing here is a clear example of premature optimization, by the way.

Comment: There is no such method.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you want to achieve, or even if it works as you want to, but you can get a `Socket` and then an `InputStream` from it.

Since you want to skip bytes, seems that work with I/O streams is the best solution.

```
    SocketChannel sock = SocketChannel.open();
    sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress("your addres or something", 80));

    InputStream ins = sock.socket().getInputStream();

    //Skip here
    ins.skip(5);
```

#### Edit

No, you cannot reuse what you have consumed with the input stream.

By the way, could you be more precise with "The allocation" problem? You can pipe the InputStream, so why do you say that you have to allocate a buffer? What is the target at the end?

#### Edit 2

There's an example that does not need to allocate K bytes

```
        ins.skip(1);

        ArrayList<Byte> bts = new ArrayList<>();

        int last = 0;
        while (last != -1) {
            last = in.read();
            bts.add((byte)last);
        }
        System.out.println(bts.stream().map(b -> new String(new byte[]{b.byteValue()})).collect(Collectors.joining()));
```

Comment: That doesn't help because it still allocate a buffer in this size. I wanted to avoid the K size allocation

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe this doesn't copy the data into the stream anyhow?   I don't know of any OS calls that allow you to simply discard TCP data off a socket.

Comment: @matansab: then implement your own java.io.InputStream.read(byte[], int, int) without buffer allocation

Comment: @JIV how are you going to get the bytes from the OS (or tell the OS to throw them away somehow) without copying them to a buffer?  I don't know of any system calls that allow that for TCP.

Comment: Well I though he wanted to avoid allocating array in InputStream.skip() method - java.io.InputStream.MAX_SKIP_BUFFER_SIZE. But now I read it again, and you're right, its not possible just skip some bytes on OS level.

Comment: Okay so he wants a magic stick? To do this at OS level he should write a native implementation or something... right?